# Wrong kernel headers version on Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kali-linux, version

```
root@Kali:~# uname -r
```

> 4.6.0-kali1-amd64

```
root@Kali:~# apt-cache search linux-headers
```

> aufs-dkms - DKMS files to build and install aufs
>
> linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-all - All header files for Linux 4.8 (meta-package)
>
> linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 4.8 (meta-package)
>
> linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.8.0-kali1-amd64
>
> linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-common - Common header files for Linux 4.8.0-kali1
>
> linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 4.8.0-kali1-rt
>
> linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.8.0-kali1-rt-amd64
>
> linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
>
> linux-headers-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
>
> linux-libc-dev-alpha-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-hppa-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-m68k-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-mips-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-mips64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-mips64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-mipsel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-powerpcspe-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-ppc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-s390x-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-sh4-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
>
> linux-libc-dev-sparc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)

The fglrx installation always says:

```
 "requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system"
```

Could anyone help me fix it ?

Comment: sounds like kali doesn't provide a compatible kernel in the repos you are using, check other available kali repos perhaps backport or testing repos. If all else fails, compile a custom kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the latest linux `image` and `headers`, run `apt-get search linux-image` then install it:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-kali1-amd64
apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-amd64
```

Restart your system and boot the `4.8` kernel version , then install `fglrx`